# disabled="#{not recordsTransferSearch.isDisabled}" does not call isDisabled() method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm trying to disable a jsf component just by defining a action method and bind it to the components "disabled" attribute.

My JSF component snippet

```
<h:form id="bulk_sch_form1">
    <a4j:commandButton id="alls" value="a. Search records form this company"
        action="#{recordsTransferSearch.actionSearch}"
        reRender="srtDlGrd, dlod_msg_grd, pending_student_table"

        disabled="#{not recordsTransferSearch.isDisabled}">

    </a4j:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Backing bean action method

```
public boolean isDisabled() {
    if (searchResults != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The searchResults just evaluating after a successful search result has been returned. But as stated in the title it's not calling the action method `isDisabled()` at all, thus nothing happens.

The action method is only calling when I'm refreshing the page.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want update <a4j:commandButton id="alls", you should include 'alls' id in reRender attribute.

Comment: @RongNK that is not directly related to my problem.

Comment: <a4j:commandButton id="alls" is used for searching, and you want to disable with condition ?

Comment: @RongNK I want to disable the button

Comment: @MMRUser In order for the `isDisabled()` method to be called again the component needs to be refreshed. Add the id to the `reRender` list.

Comment: @RongNK, Thanks I got your point

Comment: That's not an action method. That's a getter method. The `disabled` attribute takes a value expression, not a method expression. Once you understand the difference, the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should either use `disabled` as a field getter, like in `disabled="#{not recordsTransferSearch.disabled}"`, or if your EL supports method calls, i.e. is of version 2.2+, you should add empty parentheses, `()`, at the end of the method call, like in `disabled="#{not recordsTransferSearch.isDisabled()}"`.

Note that as it stands, and contrary to what you suggest in comments, `disabled="#{bean.isDisabled}"` will trigger *Property 'isDisabled' not found* error.

---

As per your comments you do not fully understand how `disabled` attribute works in JSF. It seems that you expect the button to become enabled/disabled on some javascript event and/or via some changes made by some action/actionlistener methods. This is not the case. The button is disabled/enabled **only when** EL expression of `disabled` attribute evaluates to true/false correspondingly. You may even test it: when you remove the disabled attribute of HTML `input`, effectively making it enabled in client side and will call that button, you'll see that no action method will be called, but instead its disabled attribute will be **reevaluated on server** and, as it'll evaluate to `false`, no method will be called.

To make it work as expected, you need to rerender the command button via AJAX call (by specifying its id in `reRender` attribute of another `<a4j:commandButton>` that *changes* the result of `isDisabled()` method so that it'll return `false`), or synchronously (enforcing the needed evaluation of `disabled`) so that the disabled condition will be evaluated to `false`.

Also, it would be good to go through a basic example to get a grasp of how it all works.

The view:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton id="disabled" value="Disabled command button"
                     action="#{bean.disabledSubmit}"
                     disabled="#{not bean.disabled}">
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton id="simple" value="Enable a disabled button"
                     action="#{bean.simpleSubmit}">
        <f:ajax render="disabled"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

The bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable{

    private boolean searchResults = false;

    public boolean isDisabled() {
        return searchResults;
    }

    public String disabledSubmit() {
        return null;
    }

    public String simpleSubmit() {
        searchResults = true;
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried those but it didn't work. the action method is not calling at all.

Comment: How do you handle enabling/disabling? You know that withing JSF you need to trigger that change from the server, right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with triggering, but as I have mentioned in my question I have a backing bean to handle enabling or disabling.